# Проблема с отображением текста после нажатия кнопки редактирования на Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

У меня есть приложение на *Vue-To Do List*.

Добавил туда возможность редактирования уже написанного текста заметки.

Само редактирование работает хорошо, только теперь при нажатии на кнопку edit отображается и сам текст заметки и плюс еще отдельно окно с тем же текстом для редактирования.

Есть 2 проблемы:

1. Как убрать раздвоенный текст, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку edit
   отображалось только окно редактора?
2. Как при нажатии на кнопку edit сделать фокус курсора сразу на окно
   редактора?

Мой код ниже:

```js
Vue.createApp({
    data(){
        return{
          placeholder: 'Start typing',
          inputvalue: '',
          notes: [],
          activeEdit: null
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('note')) || [];
      },
    watch: {
            notes: {
                handler: function() {
                localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(this.notes));
                },
                deep: true
            }
    },
    methods: {
        addnewtask(){
            if (this.inputvalue !== ''){
                this.notes.push({title:this.inputvalue, checked:false})
                this.inputvalue=''
            }
        },
        removetask(index){
            if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?'))
            this.notes.splice(index, 1)
        },
    editNote(note) {
      this.activeEdit = note
    },
    doneEdit(note) {
      if (!this.activeEdit) {
        return
      }
      this.activeEdit = null
      note.title = note.title.trim()
    }
    }
}).mount(app)
```

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #030303;
    background: #3d5f82;
}
h1 {
    font-weight: 500;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center;
    font-style: solid;
}
.btn {
    color: #31d78c;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #31d78c;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(231, 239, 235);
}
.btn.danger {
    color: #eb3c15;
    place-content: center;
    place-items: center;
    width: fit-content;
    border-radius: 99px;
    border: 1px solid #eb3c15;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-weight: 700;
    background: #fff;
}
.btn.danger:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color:rgb(236, 219, 219);
}
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1000px;
}
.form-control {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.form-control input,
.form-control select {
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    display: block;
    width: 95%;
    color: #2c3e50;
    padding: 0.5rem 2%;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}
.card {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    background: #fff;
}
.card.center {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.list {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.list-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0.5rem 0;
    transition: .22s all;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<style>
    [v-cloak] {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container" id="app" v-cloak>
      <div class="card">
          <h1>To Do List</h1>
          <div class="form-control">
             <input
                 type="text" 
                 v-bind:placeholder="placeholder" 
                 v-model="inputvalue"
                 v-on:keypress.enter="addnewtask"
              />
              <button class="btn" v-on:click="addnewtask">Add Task</button>
            </div>
            <hr />
            <ul class="list" v-if="notes.length !== 0"...>
                <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="note">
                    <div>
                        <input type="checkbox" v-model="note.checked"/>
                        <span :style="note.checked ? 'text-decoration: line-through' : ''">
                            {{index+1}}) {{note.title}}
                          <input type="text" v-model="note.title" 
                                 @blur="doneEdit(note)" 
                                 v-show="note==activeEdit">
                          <div>
                            <button class="btn danger" @click="editNote(note)">Edit</button>                                         </div>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn danger" v-on:click="removetask(index)">Delete</button>
                </li>
                <hr />
                <li>
                    <strong>Total: {{notes.length}}</strong>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div v-else>No task exist, please add first one.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
    <script src="Vue3.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      placeholder: 'Start typing',
      inputvalue: '',
      notes: [],
      activeEdit: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    notes: {
      handler: function() {
        // localStorage.setItem('note', JSON.stringify(this.notes));
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.initNotes();
  },
  methods: {
    initNotes() {
      /* const NOTE_FROM_LOCAL_STORAGE = localStorage.getItem('note');
      if (NOTE_FROM_LOCAL_STORAGE) {
        try {
          this.notes = JSON.parse(NOTE_FROM_LOCAL_STORAGE);
        } 
        catch(err) {
          console.err(err)
        }
      }*/
    },

    addnewtask() {
      if (this.inputvalue !== '') {
        this.notes.push({
          title: this.inputvalue,
          checked: false
        })
        this.inputvalue = ''
      }
    },

    removetask(index) {
      if (confirm('Do you really want to delete?'))
        this.notes.splice(index, 1)
    },

    editNote(note, noteIndex) {
      this.activeEdit = note;
      this.setFocusToNoteInput(noteIndex);
    },

    setFocusToNoteInput(noteIndex) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.$refs.notes[noteIndex].focus();
      });
    },

    doneEdit(note) {
      if (!this.activeEdit) {
        return
      }
      this.activeEdit = null
      note.title = note.title.trim()
    },
  }
}).mount('#app')
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #030303;
  background: #3d5f82;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  font-style: solid;
}

.btn {
  color: #31d78c;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 99px;
  border: 1px solid #31d78c;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(231, 239, 235);
}

.btn.danger {
  color: #eb3c15;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 99px;
  border: 1px solid #eb3c15;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 700;
  background: #fff;
}

.btn.danger:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: rgb(236, 219, 219);
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.form-control {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.form-control input,
.form-control select {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  display: block;
  width: 95%;
  color: #2c3e50;
  padding: 0.5rem 2%;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.card {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: #fff;
}

.card.center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.list-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 0;
  transition: .22s all;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
<div class="container" id="app" v-cloak>
  <div class="card">
    <h1>To Do List</h1>
    <div class="form-control">
      <input type="text" v-bind:placeholder="placeholder" v-model="inputvalue" v-on:keypress.enter="addnewtask" />
      <button class="btn" v-on:click="addnewtask">Add Task</button>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <ul class="list" v-if="notes.length !== 0" ...>
      <li class="list-item" v-for="(note, noteIndex) in notes" :key="noteIndex">
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" v-model="note.checked" />
          <span v-show="note !== activeEdit" :style="note.checked ? 'text-decoration: line-through' : ''">
            {{ noteIndex + 1 }}) {{ note.title }}
          </span>
          <input v-show="note === activeEdit" ref="notes" type="text" v-model="note.title" @blur="doneEdit(note)">
          <div>
            <button class="btn danger" @click="editNote(note, noteIndex)">
            Edit
          </button>
          </div>
          </span>
        </div>
        <button class="btn danger" v-on:click="removetask(index)">Delete</button>
      </li>
      <hr />
      <li>
        <strong>Total: {{notes.length}}</strong>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div v-else>No task exist, please add first one.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно вот так сделать. Я только `localStorage` код закомментировал. `stackoverflow` ругается на него.

Comment: спасибо за помощь-все работает! Единственное, немного не понтяно зачем было менять часть кода с сохранением введенных данных при обновлении страницы, возможно так более грамотно. Вообще, хочу научиться также шарить в коде, но пока только в начале. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как и где лучше учиться разработке?

Comment: Лучше всего учиться на работе. А так документация по vue.js отличная https://v3.ru.vuejs.org/ru/guide/introduction.html.